# Why does my reputation keep going down?

Tags: support

My reputation drops 1 or 2 points for, what appears to be, no reason and I don't get any notifications or warning as to why it drops.

For example, my reputation went from 1,077 yesterday to 1,075 today and I can't seem to find out why. Any suggestions as to where I can go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your reputation view in your profile: https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/58102/bdd?tab=reputation

And tick the 'Show removed posts' checkbox at the bottom.

In regards this particular case though - you had edited some posts a while back that were closed as off-topic, and the posts have been automatically deleted as part of the regular site cleanup processes that run overnight. Therefore the reputation you earned for making the edits was rolled back.

Comment: Ahh ok. I didn't realize your reputation rolled back if posts you edited get deleted. Good to know! Thanks Jon!

Comment: @BDD Some questions are beyond salvation, regardless of the edits made, so sometimes it's best to just flag / vote and then leave them alone really.

Comment: I don't think most users can see the "show removed posts" checkbox.  None appears on my profile.

Comment: @3nafish It should be there for everyone (on their own profile). However it's right at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @JonW, I'm fairly certain it's not there.  A Ctrl+F search for "removed" on my profile page returns nothing.

Comment: @3nafish On august 25th 2014 there were several posts removed that were associated to you. If you page your reputation page to cover that date do those posts display? And does the checkbox show on that particular page? I don't think any other posts you have had votes from have been removed other than on that date.

Comment: @JonW.  Yes, I'm seeing the checkbox now. Before, I missed that it had to be the reputation tab; I was looking at the main profile page.  Thank you.